# я ищу библиотеку в android studio

Tags: java, android

я ищу библиотеку в android studio для работы с интернетом, где можно было бы самому задавать заголовки http запроса, а также можно было работать с html- кодом не просто как с текстом, а как с объектами(как в jsoup)

Comment: Ну и чем jsoup не угодил?

Comment: Не следует использовать метку [tag:android-studio] для несвязанных с IDE вопросов. ПО этой метке следует задавать вопросы вида `Как сменить горячие клавишы в AndroidStudio`. А вопросы типа вашего - относятся именно в android, даже просто к Java. Использовать библиотеки можно и без IDE, просто в блокноте/терминале

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать одну библиотеку для решения двух совершенно разных задач - порочная практика. Лучше - для каждой задачи брать библиотеку решающую строго одну задачу.

Для HTTP запрос - де факто стандарт - OkHttp. Позволяет всё, что нужно, в т.ч. и управление заголовками.

Для парсинга HTML - JSOUP.

Так что просто делайте сетевой запрос через OkHttp и полученный HTML парсите через JSOUP.