# Как обновить адаптер в реальном времени

Tags: java, android, jsoup, try, catch

Я заметил что если метод содержит try и catch (то есть исключения) то функция адаптер обновляется только тогда когда цикл заканчивается, как мне решить эту проблему? MainActivity:

```
  for (int i=0; i<listlinks.size();i++ ){
                listEmails.add(String.valueOf(bb++));

                try {

                    listEmails.add(getEmailsFromLink(listlinks.get(i)));
                    listViewEmails.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                // System.out.println(getEmailsFromLink(listlinks.get(i)));

            }
```

И сам метод:

```
  private String getEmailsFromLink (String linkemail) throws IOException {
    String nnn="";
 if (linkemail.contains("vakansii")){


     Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(linkemail).data("query", "Java").userAgent("Mozilla").cookie("auth", "token").timeout(0).get();
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+");
     Matcher matcher = p.matcher(doc1.text());
     HashSet emails = new HashSet();

     while(matcher.find()) {
         emails.add(matcher.group());
         nnn= nnn + matcher.group()+"\n";
     }
    System.out.println(getEmailsFromLink(nnn));}



    return nnn;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас не в try-catch дело а в том, что вы намертво замораживаете главный поток, пока сетевой запрос не отработает. Так делать ни в коем случае нельзя. Хотя бы потому, что при медленном интернете, если запрос не отработает за 5с система выведет юзеру сообщение о том, что приложение зависло. После нескольких таких случаев система даже может предложить приложение удалить а в магазине приложений оно будет в самом низу списка аналогов, т.к. алгоритмы магазинов это учитывают.

Вот как такую задачу можно было бы решить в реальном боевом проекте:

1. Сетевой запрос делать через OkHttp. Эта библиотека позволяет получать результат запроса асинхронно: [Как отправить GET-запрос на Android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169762/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-get-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-android/1000275#1000275)
2. Полученный от сервера ответ уже обработать через [JSOUP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207491/%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%89%d1%83-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-android-studio/1207495#1207495)

Также надо иметь в виду, что внутренняя логика адаптера асинхронна